# Is there going to be a Logo Contest?

Tags: discussion, support

Are there plans or ideas floating around for a logo contest, or is that a Public-Beta stage thing?

Answer (score 4):

Getting a logo is part of getting a design, which is something that happens when a site *graduates* out of public beta.

In short, not for a long time yet.

While the site is in beta it will keep this theme that it currently has.

Answer (score 2):

Sites get a customized design when they near graduation and [that is a long way off](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257614/graduation-site-closure-and-a-clearer-outlook-on-the-health-of-se-sites). The task at hand is to gather up a collection of high quality questions so this site can get out of Private Beta. Focus on *that* now.

When the site is nearing graduation, the designers will contact you for feedback on a potential design. Typically the design is created by the designers first and it is posted for feedback and suggestions. The process of when and how this happens *has* been in flux more recently, but typically a logo contest is not really part of that process. But who knows… I've been floating various suggestions about how to get the community looped back in that process.

Answer (score 2):

no matter if we are close to graduation or not, i'd like to submit this one as my proposition

[image]

it is:

- easy to recognize
- simple
- contains stylised '3' and 'D' characters
- refers to 'layers'
- aligned to SE logo
- can be color/gray/BW and still well recognized
- can be simplified (pixelate) to create favico (min size 8x8 pixels ;)

first presented in this topic
https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/a/247/1211

Comment: I quite like this design, although I must be honest and say that I have enough blue tabs already in my browser :-). Another colour would be better, to be able to *clearly* distinguish the 3D Printing SE tabs from all of the other SE tabs that I have open. Raspberry have red, SO is orange/yellow, electrical is orangey-red. Someone told me once that the human eye is most receptive to green (although I am not sure if that is true), and from a distance - when reading writing on a white board for example, from the back of a class - red was the most feint, whereas green was the clearest.

Comment: now i get your nick :P but in terms of colors - it's just a proposition aligned to SE colors nothing else. it's just a form but the content is this stylized 3D, layers, common cup form and hot-end as a steam :)