# Community Ads! Let's make 2d ads for ourselves!

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

When 3D Printing moves into public beta, you're going to want to get the word out. And fast! One of the best ways to advertise ourselves across the entire Stack Exchange network is through community ads.

#### So what are these "Community Ads?"

Graduated sites allow the community to advertise relevant products or services within the site, using a system where the community chooses what to advertise. You can find these posts on per-site metas. Hint: these posts have the [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag!

#### Cool! What should the ad be like?

There's a few requirements for these ads. Most notably,

- They must be 300px wide by 250px tall, or double for "retina" displays
- There's a limit on file size of 150 kB.
- The image must be hosted on i.stack.imgur (the Stack Exchange image hosting service).
- Ads must be GIF or PNG (no animated GIFs).

#### What else should I know?

To facilitate easy posting to other sites, make sure that the embedded image is of the following format:

```
[![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

   [1]: http://image-url
   [2]: http://clickthrough-url
```

You can also include a message as a part of your answer with your own thoughts: why you chose some of the elements, and what sites the ads could potentially be posted to. Don't forget to critique each other as well!

**Happy Designing!**

Comment: Do you have an example of this done elsewhere?

Comment: There are many examples on [Open Source Meta](http://meta.opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/80/community-promotion-ads?lq=1)

Comment: @Zizouz212, long live unicorns! :)

Comment: @TormodHaugene You found it. Oh no.

Comment: @tbm0115 - Has this been done yet? Sorry if I am behind with the times.

Answer (score 5):

I'll try my hand at it and try to get the ball rolling.

[image: Been here?]

Comment: I think some variety of this could be nice to attract people who are already familiar with 3D printing. For other people it might not make much sense, but then, who do we want to attract?

Comment: I just pulled the photo from Google. It was either that one or a half done print of a head and spaghetti on the side lol

Comment: There seem to be many good examples in the *made* section for this model on thingiverse.
http://www.thingiverse.com/thing:44267/#made

Comment: Ha! I forgot about that! I think there was another slew of failed prints in the "Occupy Thingiverse" campaign.

Comment: "Print the Test Cube as ugly as you can and post picture of it as *I made one*" - brilliant.

Comment: We could potentially advertise to Open Source SE with Occupy Thingiverse ads lol

Comment: I like this one. Where does it need to be posted in order to get ads up and running?

Answer (score 5):

How about something like:

[image]

The post-it design is optional, naturally.

Answer (score 5):

I admire Tormod idea.

Here is my version of his picture.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Nicely drawn! I'd say I favor C. Have you tried making it in the beta theme colors (gray, blue, black?) of 3D Printing Beta?

Comment: gray blue black is better as it's more... afrificial :)

Comment: Just like the read and brown is more natural. .-) I think they both look good!

Comment: Definitely a fan of C and D. Great work!

Comment: I really like the idea AND the execution, it is a nice simplified design that appeals a lot to me. However, while it would be a great logo for the site, I don't see it advertising for our site in any way. I would not even identify it connected to 3D printing if I didn't know what it was for.

Comment: @kamuro I got an idea how to increase "the feeling of 3d printing" but I have no time to draw it. It's gonna be the same pictogram but steam/smoge will have shape more like printing head and inner fill wil form 3D letters. Despite that logo doesn't have to be 100% recognizable by it's meaning - compare M for macdonald's but not for butger itself ;)

Comment: Yeah, but the big M already is well known and doesn't advertise just with the M. As I said, as a logo it's really great. But it won't create the urge in ppl to click the ad, because they won't even know it is an advertisement instead of just good looking design. It needs to tell ppl that they want to learn about 3D printing...

Comment: u r right! i'm trying to find some time... overloaded... overheated... reset...

Comment: I like the coffee references and the logo idea, but is there anyway to make it '3-D'?

Comment: sure it is... patience please :)

Comment: I'd wear a shirt with option c of d on it! This looks awesome

Comment: Hi darth, how busy are you? Can you make some designs along [these ideas](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291/which-se-sites-should-we-target-with-community-ads?noredirect=1#comment437_291)?

Comment: heavy loaded indeed, but in short - you want me to prepare some ads for these forums?

Answer (score 3):

here is another trial of logo (kinda evolution to make it more technic and even more simple)

[image]

and favico
[image]

Comment: +1 This is my favorite over your previous designs!

Comment: ha! thanx @tbm0115

Comment: @darthpixel - Do you have the underlying images for these? I don't know what you made used to create them (photoshop, illustrator, paint, whatever), but if you have the composition files, I'd like to use them to create new ones with other (read: more) text on them.

Comment: call me outsider but i'm not using mentioned apps. i use xara and it's derivative (photo and graphics designer)

Answer (score 3):

here is another proposition
it's as "native" as possible i think :)

[image]

it's jut a draft so all those curves will be tuned

but i wanted to show the idea

Comment: \o/ That looks amazing!

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned, here's one related to the [**Occupy Thingiverse**](http://www.thingiverse.com/thing:30808) movement. It's simple, but it has a bit of history within the 3D printing community.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Using this guy to post on the facebook groups. As an admin of 3d printing hobbyists I usually see posts get 2-3k views. So We might get as high as 5k+ views. But it seems to be fairly random with Facebooks meddling with what content to show first.

Comment: I don't really exists as I don't have fb account but if this logo on fb will support our forum - let's give it a try. On the other hand - there was no formal voting for any logo here so I don't know if other members share the vision...

Comment: Hard to say if there was an impact. I'll try again when it is not christmas. Though I did get a ton of reputation from new questions those 2 weeks..