# Accepting Unanswered Questions

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions

Some might noticed that I've posted "blanket" questions to some older questions that have 1 or more answers, but unaccepted. This is partially a reminder to answer unaccepted questions if there is a valid answer (or update the question with more refined question(s)). But, I'd also like to brainstorm a couple of ways to appropriately ask to answer a question. I've got two that I've used so far today, but what are some that you all have used in the past?

**1.** Question has more than one answer, with one particularly well written answer

> I noticed that your question has a few answers available and has been open for a while, just curious if any of the available answers was able to help. If not, then what questions do you still have?

**2.** Question has 1 or more answer, with no single answer that stands out as the "correct" answer

> I noticed that your question has not had much activity lately, are you still looking for an answer to this question? How might we be able to close some gaps?

The reason I am bringing this up is to try and increase our "answer accepted" percentage. Currently <sup>(07/03/2016)</sup> there are 396 questions and using `is:question hasaccepted:no closed:no` there are 162 questions unaccepted, of which only 11 do not have answers. So, basic math tells us that roughly 40% of our questions are unaccpted. According to our [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/82438/3d-printing) page, we only have 43 users with reputaion higher than 200, we need 107 more users out of the 2,353 users total to reach this goal. Some, if not most of these users currently have a reputation higher than 100 (partially due to the at least 300 reputation on another SE site).

Answer (score 2):

I'm glad you bring this up: I have to admit I have not been using these filters very much. Reviving old unanswered questions seems like a good idea, and I think both of your replies are good examples.

In addition, I think we could shed some light onto the other beta goals as well. What do you think about more actively giving good quality questions and answers +1? I believe increasing the overall reputation will encourage users to come back, while also helping us reach our beta goals.

Furthermore, that community add we have been discussing [over here](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76/community-ads-lets-make-2d-ads-for-ourselves), does anyone know how to actually get that going? :-)

Comment: That's a good question for Zizous (forget the correct spelling)

Comment: @tbm0115 I think (and I may be wrong as I've only spent the last 10 minutes reading at these for the first time) that you have to go to any graduated site's meta and find a community-ad tagged question, such as https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/community-ads, and then submit your ad as an answer. So your example [here](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76/community-ads-lets-make-2d-ads-for-ourselves#answer-126) you need to submit it as an answer (I think)... Actually I'm wrong (those seem very old meta posts) and haven't the faintest idea what one has to do.