# Which SE sites should we target with community ads?

Tags: discussion, advertising

In the interest of upping our visits and regular users, and with respect to this meta post, [Community Ads! Let's make 2d ads for ourselves!](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76/community-ads-lets-make-2d-ads-for-ourselves), we have these suggestions for advertising SE.3D Printing, so far:

- [SE.Arduino](https://arduino.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2517)
- [SE.Raspberry Pi](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1045)
- [SE.Engineering](https://engineering.stackexchange.com) - Not accepting ads
- [SE.Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6475)
- [SE.Blender](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2440)
- [SE.Academia](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3961)
- [SE.Graphic Design](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3348/82775)

Still in Beta (so, not accepting ads, yet):

- [SE.Robotics](https://robotics.stackexchange.com)
- [SE.Reverse Engineering](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com) (?)

and also (if possible)

- [SE.Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com)

Any other suggestions?

**NOTE**: Anyone and everyone is invited to post an ad as an answer to the "Community Promotion Ads" meta posts on these various sites. If it gets 6 (or more) votes then we get a free advertisement...

---

To recap, taking information from here, [Community Promotion Ads - 2018](https://mechanics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1972/community-promotion-ads-2018):

> #### How does it work?
>
> The answers you post to this question must conform to the following
>   rules, or they will be ignored.
>
> 1. All answers should be in the exact form of:
>
>    ```
>    [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]
>
>      [1]: http://image-url
>      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
>    ```
>
>    Please do not add anything else to the body of the post. If you
>      want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
>
>    2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements,
>         this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.
>
> #### Image requirements
>
> - The image that you create must be 300 x 250 pixels, or double that if high DPI.
> - Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
> - Must be GIF or PNG
> - No animated GIFs
> - Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB
> - If the background of the image is white or partially white, there must be a 1px border (2px if high DPI) surrounding it.
>
> #### Score Threshold
>
> There is a minimum score threshold an answer must meet (currently 6)
>   before it will be shown on the main site.
>
> You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click
>   stats here.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 - Thanks :-)

Comment: My general thinking of how we could do these ads is if the targeted site has a regular icon (like the raspberry in Raspberry Pi), we could show a print head putting down lines just about finishing the icon. Then also, we could stagger the colors of the icon being drawn to conform with the "general" colors of SE. Raspberry Pi, Arduino, and EE.SE would be very easy, I think. Other ones may be a bit more challenging, or we might possibly need to go a different direction with them.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 - that sounds good. Im not much of an artist. But....

Comment: ... @darth pixel is quite a good designer, maybe he is up to [the challenge](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76/community-ads-lets-make-2d-ads-for-ourselves#comment440_153)?

Comment: I pinged darth pixel to see if they would offer up the stuff they had on here from before, but got nothing back. His work is what got me thinking about what I wrote above.