# 3DPrinting.SE site logo, can it be changed?

Tags: discussion, design

Our site has the default Stack Exchange logo (text balloon with text 3D), is it possible to change this logo?

I was thinking of something like this:

[image]

or

[image]

If it is possible, we could try to write out a competition and vote! E.g. instead of the lines, the printed image of 3D

Comment: That's quite a clever logo! :-)

Comment: Clearly it should be a benchy.

Comment: With us being graduated, we need to have our Logo!

Comment: [Graduation is now independent from site designs.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/263905/335251) That said, [we've recently been working on creating designs for some of the sites that have been waiting the longest](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/378976/335251).

Answer (score 4):

Yes, we can! Or at least discuss if we like a different logo.

From [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/298341/) on Meta Stack Exchange question "[What's the process to change a site logo?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/298338/whats-the-process-to-change-a-site-logo)" we can read:

> If you have an issue with a logo on a site, the best place to start is to open a discussion on that site's meta. Tag it [discussion](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discussion) and [design](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/design), and see what the overall community feeling is.

Another part reads:

> [Community managers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99338/who-are-the-community-team-and-what-do-they-do) monitor per-site metas, so if/when the discussion concludes and the site's community largely supports a change, they can bring your concerns to the design team.

There is no specific mention if Beta state sites can modify the logo, Beta sites share the smae layout set out by the Stack Exchange designers:

> Our designers come up with the overall site design (including the logo), with some input from the communities. (With the exception of sites that are still in beta or have only recently graduated - those all share the same design.)

However, we can start a discussion whether we would like to have a different logo/favicon. Feel free to add your thoughts ans an aswer to the question.

Comment: Are there any particular parameter constraints, i.e. height and width?

Comment: Favicon.ico should be 32 x 32 pixels. Images used at https://stackexchange.com/sites are 48 x 48 pixels, although I remember larger images for larger communities in the past; it's possible images were scaled up or down. Probably safest to stick with a 265 color or internet-safe palate.

Answer (score 1):

i'd like to remind my old suggestion :)

[image]

here is the original post
https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/a/248/1211